# Passing a parameter sent by a form to the controler in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller

I am new to Laravel programming, and now I want to delete from 2 tables (projects and pictures) in plain PHP  I can do this:

delete the project from projects:

```
$sql1 = delete * from projects where project_id = 1;
```

delete all his photos

```
$sql2 = delete * from pictures where project_id = 1;
```

I want to do this in my `route.php` here is my code

```
Route::delete('/project/{project}', function (Project $project) {
    DB::table('pics')->where('projectId', '=', $project)->delete();
    $project -> delete();
    return redirect('/');
});
```

I am able to delete the project but not its picture?

what can I do?

Comment: Laravel build automatically the `$project` object from the id, so if you want to delete it using the id, you have to retrieve it from the `Project` object `$project->id`. this feature is called Router Model Binding https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using type hinting:

```
... (Project $project) { ...
```

So when you do this:

```
DB::table('pics')->where('projectId', '=', $project)->delete();
```

You're really saying "where projectId is equal to this object".

You have two options. Either 1) don't use type hinting:

```
Route::delete('/project/{project}', function ($project) {
    DB::table('pics')->where('projectId', '=', $project)->delete();
    $project -> delete();
    return redirect('/');
});
```

Or 2) use type hinting properly:

```
Route::delete('/project/{project}', function (Project $project) {
    DB::table('pics')->where('projectId', '=', $project->id)->delete();
    $project -> delete();
    return redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So well i'd like to add more to the previous answer, just to say *why* is in that way.

What you can do here is just

```
Route::delete('/project/{project}', function (Project $project) {
    DB::table('pics')->where('projectId', '=', $project->id)->delete();
});
```

That's because **Laravel** build automatically the `$project` object from its id, so if you want to delete it using the id, you have to retrieve it from the `Project` object `$project->id`.

This feature is called **Route Model Binding**

> Laravel route model binding provides a convenient way to inject model instances into your routes. For example, instead of injecting a user's ID, you can inject the entire Project model instance that matches the given ID.

See more https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding